# Функция rand генерирует постоянно одинаковые числа

Tags: c++, случайные-числа

Как сгенерировать 2 числа так, чтобы 1 число обязательно было меньше 2-го. Функция rand генерирует постоянно одинаковые числа.

Comment: Приведите, пожалуйста, кусок Вашего проблемного кода

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Создайте генерацию по сиду, от системного времени в милисекундах.
Сгенерируйте первое число.
Сгенерируйте второе число, найди модуль от деления на первое.

```
r1 = srand(GetTickCount());
r2 = srand(GetTickCount());
r2%=r1;
```

Comment: А если r2 < r1?

Comment: r1 = 77
r2 = 66
(r2/r1)mod = 0
r2%r1 = r2 -((r2/r1)mod)*r1
Ответ: если r2 < r1 то число r2 не изменится

Answer (score 1):

```
x = rand();
y = rand();
y += y>=x;

if (x>y)
  swap(x, y);
```